# Enumeration Type error - Unable to create a constant C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

What I am trying to do is that, my `PackageModel` doesn't have an item `Account`. So I created a `ViewModel` (`PackageViewModel`) So I can add an `Account` item.

I am getting the following error. Can someone help me sort it ?

> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'MyPROJ.Models.Account '. Only primitive types or enumeration types
>   are supported in this context.

Model is follows:

```cs
public class PackageModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

VIEWMODEL is as follows:

```cs
public class PackageViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Account acc {get; set;}
}
```

From my controller I am doing the following:

```cs
Account a = new db.Account.Find(currentLoggedInUser);
var xxx = db.PackageModel.Where(y => y.ID== 1)
            .Select(x => new PackageViewModel()
            {
                ID= x.ID,
                acc = a
            });

return (xxx.ToList());
```

VIEW

```html
<div class="myall">
    @Html.Partial("_SomePage", @Model.First().Account)    
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `@Model.First().acc` since `PackageViewModel` doesn't have a property called `Account`?  Note this is why you should declare the type of your model.

Comment: The @ mark is not required when you pass the custom data to your partial view @Html.Partial("_SomePage", Model.First().acc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use closure-captured variables in a Linq-to-Entities query which are non-trivial types.

```
Account a = db.Account.Find( currentLoggedInUser );
var xxx = db.PackageModel.Where(y => y.ID== 1)
        .Select(x => new PackageViewModel()
        {
            ID= x.ID,
            acc = a // <-- you're capturing `a` which is an `Account`, a class type, not a trivial value or object
        });
```

Change it so that the the `Select` happens in Linq-to-Objects after the Linq-to-Entities query has completed, by using either `ToList` or `AsEnumerable`:

```
Account a = db.Account.Find( currentLoggedInUser );
var xxx = db.PackageModel
        .Where( p => p.ID == 1 ) // <-- this part is Linq-to-Entities
        .AsEnumerable() // <-- this causes the rest of the Linq construct to be evaluated in Linq-to-Objects
        .Select( p => new PackageViewModel() // <-- this part is Linq-to-Objects
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            acc = a // <-- now you can capture non-trivial values
        });
```

...however I notice you're using `Where` but with a predicate that will return a single element (assuming `ID` is unique), you should use `SingleOrDefault` instead:

```
Account acc = db.Account.Find( currentLoggedInUser );
Package package = db.PackageModel.SingleOrDefault( p => p.ID == 1 );
if( package == null ) throw new InvalidOperationException("Package not found");

PackageViewModel vm = new PackageViewModel() { ID = package.ID, Acc = acc };
return this.View( vm );
```